# Raising forest function level and domain function level

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain-controller, windows-server-2019

So I am in the process of upgrading all domain controllers from 2008R2 to 2019, I know one of the requirement need to meet if I want to raise the forest and domain functional level to 2019 is to upgrade all the domain controllers to server2019.

My question is does it include the read-only domain controllers? We have few read-only domain controllers at the remote sites.

Comment: Can you try upgrading the functional level to 2019 and see if it complains? None of the documentation I can find about RODCs indicate that they function any differently with regard to domain or forest functional levels. I strongly suspect you'll need to have *all* domain controllers at 2019 in order to upgrade the functional level, but I can't find any documentation that would make me confident enough to write it up as an answer. Do you have a test domain that you can experiment with?

Comment: thanks, i searched a lot, no such info as well, all it says is all domain controllers must be on the same level. I guess I have to push the button to find out tho.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no such thing as Windows Server 2019 forest and domain functional level. Windows Server 2019 domain controllers can maximally have Windows Server 2016 forest and domain functional level. To raise the forest and domain functional level to that level you can only have Windows Server 2019 and Windows Server 2016 domain controllers in your forest, regardless if they are writable or read only domain controllers.